# c++, Identifier is undefined when part of the code is put in another cpp file

Tags: c++, undefined

i'm sorry if the question layout is weird or something this is my first time asking a question. I have started learning c++ a week ago and now that i know how to create a window with GLFW I would like to clean up my code and make it nicer. I tried to put the "create window" stuff inside a .cpp file named "window.cpp" and then import it to the main file. but when i take out the GLFWCreateWindow function it doesn't recognize the window name "w_gill" in the swapbuffer, windowshouldclose and destroywindow functions. Can anyone please help me?

Here is the Main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "window.cpp"

int main(){
    do{
        createWindow();
        glfwSwapBuffers(w_gill);
        glfwPollEvents();
    } while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(w_gill));

    glfwDestroyWindow(w_gill);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

And the Window.cpp file:

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

int windowWidth = 1920 / 2;
int windowHeight = 1080 / 2;

int createWindow(){
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow* w_gill;
    w_gill = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Gillow", NULL, NULL);

    if (!w_gill)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(w_gill);
    glfwSetInputMode(w_gill, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't include translation units. Compile them separately and link them together.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how do i link them together?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code being in separate files - `w_gill` is a local variable in the function. You can return its value and use it in `main`.

Comment: If you started learning C++ a week ago, you may find GLFW and 3D graphics being slightly too ambitious a starting point if you're not very familiar with them already. I would recommend that you pick up [a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I got it, I had to put

```
GLFWwindow* w_gill;
int createWindow();
```

inside of the main.cpp file so they are linked. Thanks for responding anyway.

Comment: You should put those declarations in a separate header file (*.h) that would be included in both main.cpp and Window.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has to do with the "[scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29)" or lifetime that a variable has in [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#C). The scope of `w_gill` is local to its containing function, and as such, there is no visibility to that variable outside of the function. In addition to moving the `createWindow()` function to its own .CPP file, you must have made some other changes, as even if it was still in `main.cpp` you would still have the same issue.